# What does the DRF Format option mean

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for the first time and I would like to know what the "format" in the following code snippet from their website do:

```
class CommentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # do stuff...

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # do stuff...
```

I read the docs, but I am not sure how it works still. Can someone enlighten me with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

Suppose their is an **APIView** with following code :

```
class HelloAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format):
        # do stuff...

    def post(self, request, format):
        # do stuff...
```

And endpoint url for **HelloAPIView** is :

```
http://example.com/api/users
```

Now if u want the data in response to be in **json** format then the URL you would access
will be like

```
http://example.com/api/users.json
```

So when you access urls like above , then value " **json** " will be passed as 3rd argument (1st is *self* , 2nd is *request* and 3rd is *format*) to **get()** or **post()** methods of **HelloAPIView**.

So basically **format** parameter is used to define in which format you want the response.

For more details refer

1. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/
2. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#adding-optional-format-suffixes-to-our-urls

Answer (score 0):

Format is added to handel multiple content types in DRF

Using format suffixes gives us URLs that explicitly refer to a given format, and means our API will be able to handle URLs such as

**http://localhost/api/items/4.json**

Adding format-suffix patterns to each individual entry in the URLconf for your API is error-prone and non-DRY, so REST framework provides a shortcut to adding these patterns to your URLConf.

for more details refer [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#adding-optional-format-suffixes-to-our-urls)

Comment: Thanks for the article, I am still a little confuse. `urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html'])` How does that play out?